# How to compare value with multiple modified values from another table in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using Google BigQuery and I got the following issue:

I have a table (**A**) like this:

```
|         time           |     request     |
|------------------------|-----------------|
|2019-09-24 11:10:00 UTC | fakewebsite.com |
|2019-09-24 11:10:00 UTC | realwebsite.com |
|........................|.................|
|2019-09-24 11:10:00 UTC | foobwebsite.com |
|2019-09-24 11:10:00 UTC | barrwebsite.com |
```

And another table (`B`) like this:

```
|   blacklist   |
|---------------|
|    foo.com    |
|       ...     |
|    bar.com    |
```

I want to make a query that will grab a modified version of the values inside the blacklist field of table **B** as follows:

`SPLIT(NET.REG_DOMAIN(blacklist), CONCAT('.',NET.PUBLIC_SUFFIX(blacklist)))[OFFSET(0)] AS to_exclude` --this will return only "foo" from "foo.com"

and then return all values from the `request` field of table **A** where none of the `to_exclude` was found.

I know how to do this for one value but I don't know how to do this for multiple. I am looking for something like the following:

```
#standardSQL
WITH tmp_blacklist AS
    (SELECT
        SPLIT(NET.REG_DOMAIN(blacklist), CONCAT('.',NET.PUBLIC_SUFFIX(blacklist)))[OFFSET(0)] AS to_exclude
    FROM 
        mydataset.B)

SELECT
    request
FROM
    mydataset.A
WHERE  
    request NOT LIKE ("%value1%", "%value2%", ..., "%valuen%") -- I can't use OR along with the NOT LIKE since the values are too many and they will change.
```

The `n values` are the values of the `tmp_blacklist` table.

Also if I don't define the table with the `WITH` and I define it after the `NOT LIKE` I am going to get the following error: `Scalar subquery produced more than one element` which makes sense if `LIKE` expects only one element. But then again that's half of the job done if it get's fixed since I want the `"%value%"` and not just the `value` of the table.

Now I searched online for a way to do this and I found people saying that it can't be done and then some workarounds with combinations of `LIKE` and `IN` where people said it will be very slow if one of the tables grows to have tons of data(my case).

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `not exists`:

```
SELECT a.request
FROM mydataset.A a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tmp_blacklist bl
                  WHERE a.request LIKE CONCAT('%', bl.to_exclude, '%'
                 );
```

Note that this can be expensive.  You might want to test constructing the exclusion string as:

```
'value1|value2|value3'
```

and then using regular expressions.